# ejs-calendar by Syncfusion does not detect when a user deselects a day from calendar popup

Tags: typescript, angular12

Hey guys this is my first ever post on this website. I am working on a little angular 2 project and for some reason I cannot identify what event is emitted when I deselect a day from the calendar popup. Currently my HTML looks like this

```
            id="secondcalendar"
            class="datepicker"
            #ejCalendars
            [(ngModel)]="dateValue2"
            (change)="onChange($event)"
            [isMultiSelection]="multiSelect">
</ejs-calendar>

and Typescript looks like this
onChange(event: { value: Date }): void {
    console.log("DATE PASSED: ", event.value);
    }
```

Currently I can capture every single day I selected each time using (change)="onChange($event)", however if I deselect a date on the same popup then this event only sends back the last date that was selected and not the date I de-selected. How can I get the date that was deselected so I can later manipulate my array of dates that were selected?
This is what the datepicker looks like: https://prnt.sc/oLBaspAqNa7s

If you view the screenshot in that link I selected the 4th, 5th and 6th of January but I deselected the 6th which is why it is no longer highlighted but (change)="onChange($event)" returns the last value that was selected when in fact I wanted the 6th(which is what was deselected).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was taking the wrong approach in getting the updated values when a deselection is done, there was already a "values" property which I could have just accessed and pass it to my ts file each(tracked this with "(change)" event) time the calendar is utilized